# Creating a table with mutual uniqueness across multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Heyo,
I have a table with two columns, parentServer and appealServer.
Both are `VARCHAR(24)`s, and my goal is to have mutual uniqueness across the two columns.

my current approach is to create a table in the database called dbam;

```sql
USE dbam;
CREATE TABLE linkedservers (
  parentServer varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  appealServer varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (parentServer ,appealServer),
  UNIQUE KEY parentServer (parentServer ,appealServer),
  CONSTRAINT CHK_Crosslink CHECK (parentServer <> appealServer or parentServer is null or appealServer is null)
)
```

However this still allows for an entry in `appealServer` to exist in `parentSerevr`, as seen in the image below, and vice versa.

[image]

I expect for the `CHECK` constraint to fire off when I insert the values into the table

```sql
INSERT INTO linkedservers (parentServer,appealServer)
       VALUES ('${supposedParent.id}','${supposedAppeal.id}')
```

That being said, Is there a way to achieve mutual uniqueness?
that being that any entry in the second column cannot exist in the first column

**How to recreate this**;

Sample Data;

```
855794220651380776
855794252025167872
856315856358342656
```

enter two of the ids into parentServer and appealServer respectively,

```sql
INSERT INTO linkedservers (parentServer,appealServer)
       VALUES ('855794220651380776','855794252025167872')
```

then attempt to use the appealServer id as a parentSerevr id with a new id for the appealServer

```sql
INSERT INTO linkedservers (parentServer,appealServer)
       VALUES ('855794252025167872','856315856358342656')
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  A clear explanation of "mutual uniqueness" is also desirable.

Comment: You don't need the UNIQUE INDEX  as all PRIMARY KEYS are unique

Comment: Do you mean unique within the whole table, or just not equal to each other in the same row?

Comment: @Barmar within the whole table

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You'd need to use a `NOT EXISTS` test, but subqueries are not allowed in `CHECK` constraints.

Comment: Can you redesign your table? Just have a single, unique `server` column, and another column indicating whether it's a `parent` or `appeal`.

Comment: @Barmar I can definitely redesign the table, was just seeing if this was possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a trigger for such checks.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE linkedservers (
>   parentServer varchar(24) NOT NULL,
>   appealServer varchar(24) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (parentServer ,appealServer),
>   UNIQUE KEY parentServer (parentServer ,appealServer),
>   CONSTRAINT CHK_Crosslink CHECK (parentServer <> appealServer or parentServer is null or appealServer is null)
> )
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER before_linkedservers_insert
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON linkedservers FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>
>     IF  EXISTS(    SELECT 1
>         FROM linkedservers
>
>     WHERE appealServer = NEW.parentServer) THEN
>         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
>             SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'is aleady appleal server';
>     END IF; 
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO linkedservers (parentServer,appealServer) VALUES ('855794220651380776','855794252025167872')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO linkedservers (parentServer,appealServer) VALUES ('855794252025167872','856315856358342656')
> ```

> ```
> is aleady appleal server
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c62f32e37fbe20ba8aa3324a818144a)*

Comment: This works, But when attempting to enter a parentServer with a value that's not unique, it goes through, which I believe `UNIQUE KEY parentServer` should have stopped, 
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92bccc54bcb73a33c5fea9f16cc97678)

Comment: Yes you defined  a combination to be unique, if you only want one parentServer  you have to define it alone a unique.

Comment: ah yes, I see @nbk, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, not tested. Wired design, pseudo code.

Servers, no more then two servers in a link

```
CREATE TABLE servers (
  Server varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  role int not null check role in (1,2),
  linkId int not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (Server),
  UNIQUE KEY lnk (link, role)
)
```

Ensure both roles are present. Only links in Goodlinks are valid.

```
Create table Goodlinks(
  Linkid not null primary key,
  role1Id int not null check role1Id = 1 default 1,
  role2Id int not null check role2Id = 2 default 2,
  FK r1(Linkid,role1Id) references servers(linkid,role)
  FK r2(Linkid,role2Id) references servers(linkid,role)
)
```

A row in goodLinks prevents a linked server deletion.